# How to bind data to scope object that i can use it in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-http

I am getting a response from the server and due to async behavior I instantiated scope object first before the call and used it in method. I am getting the response in self-object but unable to bind it $scope object which I will be using in my view to repeat.

Request you all to please guide me on same.

```
var self = $scope;

$scope.nearme = function($scope) {

    var lat = localStorage.getItem('lat');
    var lon = localStorage.getItem('lon');
    var request = $http.get("functions/functions.php?activity=getlocalnews&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon).then(function (response) {
         self = response; 
        return self; // this will be `data` in the next chained .then() functions
    });

   request.then(function (data) {
        self= (data.data)
        console.log(self);
   });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign data to a varible

```
self.array=[];
request.then(function (data) {
   self.array=data.data;
});
```

Comment: How to use it in view? can you please help